# Regarding exactly n occurrence of character in regex

Tags: java, regex, tokenize

I was trying to break string in tokens with + = == <= >= != || { } when they occur outside double quotes. But it is tokenizing with single occurrence of | < > !. That is not required. So how to handle it?

```
String line1= "sa2dvf=s||a|df&&v<gdsf==ds!gv!=fdgv\"fvdsvg=kjhbhbj==\"";
String regex = "[\\{\\}+={!=}{<=}{>=}{||}](?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)";
String[] tokens = line1.split(regex, -1);
for(String val : tokens) {
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

And it's output is:

```
sa2dvf
s

a
df&&v
gdsf

ds
gv

fdgv"fvdsvg=kjhbhbj=="
```

But required is:

```
sa2dvf
s
a|df&&v<gdsf
ds!gv
fdgv"fvdsvg=kjhbhbj=="
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this lookahead regex for splitting:

```
String[] arr = str.split("(?:[<>=!]=|\\|\\||[+=\\{}])(?=(?:(?:[^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rMxWgJ/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(?:[<>=!]=|\\|\\||[+=\\{}])`: Match one of the operators we want to split on
- `(?:[^"]*"){2}` finds a pair of quotes
- `(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*` finds 0 or more pair of quotes
- `[^"]*$` makes sure we don't have any more quotes after last matched quote
  So `(?=...)` asserts that we have even number of quotes ahead thus matching symbols outside the quoted string only.